# How do I disable convention and refactor linting globally?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, lint

I've been having problems configuring Pylint in VS Code. I can't figure out how to disable the convention and refactor linting. They should be [disabled by default](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_default-pylint-rules) but they are not. Maybe because I also installed pylint-django but I can't find settings for it. This is what it looks like

[image]

I have my own strict conventions and refactor rules so these hints are nothing but annoying. Is there a way to get rid of convention and refactor linting globally or for the user or the entire project permanently? I still want to keep errors and warnings, of course.

I tried `pylint --disable=R,C *.py` and restarted the server and VS code. Nothing changed. I also tried creating `.pylintrc` and putting `disable=R,C` in there, but that also had no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `settings.json` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> -> `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`):

```
{
    ...,
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--disable=R,C", "*.py"],
    ...
}
```